# Iptables firewall forward

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am currently working on linux router and i am not able to firewall it the way i would like.

Router has three interfaces - WAN, which is Mobile Broadband Private subnet `172.18.15.0/24` which is save and has device `172.18.15.2` Private subnet `10.0.0.0/24` which I don't trust. WAN is for accessing it via OpenVPN and is routers default gateway.

Router IPs are `172.18.15.1` and `10.0.0.1`. In iptables I have DNAT rule to forward port `80` traffic from `10.0.0.1` to `172.18.15.2` witch MASQUERADE on way back.

This part works fine.

What is my concern is that when anyone from private subnet chooses `10.0.0.1` as its default gateway or creates route to `172.18.15.0/24` via `10.0.0.1` then it exposes `172.18.15.2` too. This behavior I would like to stop so the only way to access `172.18.15.2` web is through address `10.0.0.1`.

If I cancel forwarding, I cancel DNAT too, which is problem.

One way which come to me is install apache and create reverse proxy. However i am not sure if it is the right way and correct way.

Thanks for suggestions!

#### EDIT:

`172.18.15.2` is simple device. It can have only its own address and address of gateway, in this case `172.18.15.1`. It is responding because I have set in `/etc/sysctl.conf` `net.ipv4.ip_forwarf=1`

Here is dump of `iptables-save -c`
enp1s0 is interface for 10.0.0.0/24
enp2s0 is interface for 172.18.15.0/24
wwx582c80139263 is interface for mobile broadband gateway

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Apr 16 08:27:45 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [840:388180]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [643:92809]
[0:0] -A INPUT -d 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -d 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr 16 08:27:45 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Apr 16 08:27:45 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [10:648]
:INPUT ACCEPT [10:648]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11:770]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [11:770]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to- 
destination 172.18.15.2:80
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.15.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -o wwx582c80139263 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr 16 08:27:45 2018
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "witch MASQUERADE on way back" ? I can see the role of DNAT, but I don't see the use of MASQUERADE (if that's what you meant). anyway, that shouldn't change a way to prevent this, but I'd rather be sure I understand the whole picture. Can you confirm that 172.18.15.2 has a route to 10.0.0.0/24 in your current settings, or is that what the MASQUERADE is for? actually dumping the whole `iptables-save -c` in your question would help

Comment: Thanks, i have updated question with information you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a reverse proxy (which should insert a `X-Forwarded-For` header for logging purposes), and removing network forwarding, would be a clean solution. The solution below, should be clearly understood to avoid unexpected effects with further iptables rule changes.

That said...

### The problem

- LAN `10.0.0.0/24`'s nodes musn't use Router as a router, at least not to reach `172.18.15.0/24`. Some do anyway.
- Router provides services located at `172.18.15.0/24` (`172.18.15.2:80`) for `10.0.0.0/24` nodes, by using DNAT and forwarding.
- once packets reach the filter/FORWARD chain, there's no way to distinguish if they were initially destined for `10.0.0.1` and then DNATed or if they were sent directly to `172.18.15.2` (which should be forbidden).

### The solution

So the classification has to be done before NAT happens: in the mangle table, as can be seen in this [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) schematic.  This unique rule is enough to handle it:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 172.18.15.0/24 -j DROP
```

But usually, for better management, there should be a separation of roles: mangle to alter (not drop) or here mark, and the filter table (the default) to filter and drop. That's possible by using a mark at the mangle step, and matching this mark for dropping at the filter step. So this is equivalent:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 172.18.15.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP
```

(and to be really complete: `iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP` to prevent access to `172.18.15.1`)

Either method is equivalent. Of course if it's really only the device 172.18.15.2 which has to be protected, just replace `-d 172.18.15.0/24` with `-d 172.18.15.2`.

UPDATE: an easier method relying on conntrack (which is already in use because of NAT) can be used: querying [conntrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#Connection_tracking) to know if the packet was actually DNATed, and dropping it if not. So this simplifies things, because that's only one rule, and simply in the filter/FORWARD chain. So as a 3rd method, instead of the rules above:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 172.18.15.0/24 -m conntrack ! --ctstate DNAT -j DROP
```

Also the following line is useless and can be removed. PREROUTING changed the destination with DNAT, so the flow never reaches INPUT but goes throught the FORWARD chain instead:

```
[0:0] -A INPUT -d 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I do not have hardware to test it at my disposal. However, because i can go reverse proxy way, i will use it. How to do it with mangle helped me why my solution did not work.

Comment: @FilipRak just in case and to be thorough I added a 3rd, simpler, iptables method